# Sequence related to degrees of elements of the Selberg class

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fourier-transform, l-functions

Say an increasing arithmetic sequence  $ (s_n)_{n\ge 0} $ is 'sensible' if every element thereof is the degree of some function belonging to the Selberg class. Let  $ a_s $ its reason and  $ f_s  : =1/a_s $. For example the sequence defined by  $ s_n=n $ is sensible.

Is the Selberg class stable under the transformation  $ a_{n}(F)\mapsto a_{n}(F)e^{2i\pi.n.f_s}$ where  $ a_{n} (F)$ is the  $ n $ -th coefficient in the Dirichlet series defining  $ F $ for  $\Re(s)>1 $?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is no. Elements of the Selberg class have Euler products, and twisting the coefficients by additive characters destroys this multiplicativity.

Comment: Unless  $ f_s $ is an integer.